# Can a convex polytope with $f$ facets have more than $f$ facets when projected into $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, linear-programming, affine-geometry

Let $P$ be a convex polytope in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $n$ vertices and $f$ facets.
Let $\text{Proj}(P)$ denote the projection of $P$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Can $\text{Proj}(P)$ have more than $f$ facets?

In the general case, each successive projection can increase the number of facets from $f$ to $\left\lfloor \frac{f^2}{2} \right\rfloor$, but I'm wondering if $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a special case.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Consider the polytope in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $8$ vertices at coordinates $(\pm 1, \pm 2, 1), (\pm 2, \pm 1, -1)$.  Geometrically this looks like a cube where the top face is stretched in the direction of the $y$-axis and the bottom face is stretched in the direction of the $x$-axis, but it still has the face structure of a cube and in particular has $6$ facets.

It's projection onto the first two coordinates is clearly an octagon, and hence has two more facets than the original polytope.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample.  Does requiring $P$ to be facet-transitive and vertex-transitive have an effect?

Comment: That I'm not sure about.  I'll note that that example is vertex transitive (but not facet transitive).  I will say that this does hold for all regular (i.e. flag transitive) polytopes, with the possible exception of the 120-cell, which is unlikely but I don't want to take the time to analyze it.

Comment: So more generally, the analogous deformed prism with base an n-gon shows that one can obtain a 2n-gon as a projection of a polyhedron with n+2 facets.

Answer (score 25):

Your question is essentially about extension complexity.  In general, the *extension complexity* of a polytope $P$ is the minimum number of facets over all polytopes $Q$ which project to $P$.  You are interested in the extension complexity of polygons.  [Fiorini, Rothvoß, and Tiwary](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.0371) proved that *regular* $n$-gons have extension complexity $O(\log n)$.  For lower bounds, they give examples of $n$-gons which have extension complexity $\sqrt{2n}$.

It is an [open question](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/extension_complexity_of_convex_polygons) if there exists for infinitely many $n$, an $n$-gon with extension complexity $\Omega(n)$.
**Edit.** [Shitov](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.0728) has recently shown that every convex $n$-gon has extension complexity at most $147 n^{2/3}$, which resolves the open question in the negative.

As a bonus, here is a picture of the polytope in Nate's answer (courtesy of Samuel Fiorini).

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Another, combinatorially minimal, counterexample of such a polytope $P$ (with only five facets) is the convex hull of the six vertices $(\pm2, 0, 0)$, $(\pm1, \pm1, 1)$. Its projection to the $xy$-plane is a hexagon. The minimality of the number of vertices and the number of facets is easy to prove.

Comment: ---------------

---- Nice! ----

---------------